# How to make a calculator discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, calculator

How to make a discord bot so when I input the following it calculates it:
INPUT:
2.2x100 2.8x100-10%

OUTPUT:
output should be the result of the following:
2.8*100 - 2.2*100 and then minus 10% of that,

(that equation is subject to change)
How would I do this?

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: I cannot figure it out, could you help me?

Comment: Can't figure what out? If you can break the problem into something specific it will get better answers

Comment: I don't know what to write and how to even start

Comment: Start by writing a calculator program. Once you've built it, focus on making it accessible through a discord bot. Don't tackle both at once. Start with the bot first if you like.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an easy task (if you don't want to be unsafe and `eval()` code).

You need an **infix parser** that takes into account **order of operations** (priorities). If there are parenthesis in your operation, it will be even more complex.

You will then need to evaluate the result with a function that executes an **abstract syntax tree** generated by the parser (AST).

There is probably libraries that make this easier without being unsafe, but make a google search about all the terms I talked about so you can learn more.

EDIT: also take a look at this link. Not beginner stuff.

[Infix Calculator Expression Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853774/infix-calculator-expression-parser)

EDIT 2: Just in case you want the easiest solution with `eval()`, be careful. A skilled attacker can destroy your computer with malicious code. If you just `eval()` whatever is sent to the bot, they could really destroy / take control of your computer. Be careful.

Comment: Could you help me write the code?

Comment: @pydev it is not an easy task to write infix parsers, even for advanced programmers. Make a quick google search, you'll understand. You probably have libraries who help you achieve your task, but if you want to write your code, start with researching infix parsers.